# Kinect problems: error setting TrackingMode for a video object

Tags: matlab, kinect

I am working on one project with Matlab and Kinect sensor.

It's a `kinect V2` and `Matlab R2016a`. I have a function for getting a live feed for tracking the joints of a person which will create a skeletal image. The problem is that there is one part of the code that it keeps getting stuck at and I don't know how to fix it.

I am writing this line but it doesn't work:

```
set(getselectedsource(depthVid),'TrackingMode','Skeleton')
```

When I wrote this, I saw this message :

> The name 'TrackingMode' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'videosource'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image acquisition [documentation example](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/imaq/examples/using-the-kinect-r-for-windows-r-from-image-acquisition-toolbox-tm.html#d119e2581) for using the Kinect, we see how the skeleton TrackingMode can be set

```
depthSrc = getselectedsource(depthVid);
depthSrc.TrackingMode = 'Skeleton';
```

i.e. use dot indexing, not the `set` function.

Comment: Yes I tried this but it didn't work. I think my Kinect hasn't got TrackingMode @Wolfie

Answer (score 0):

I did as follows below and it worked for me,

```
  depthSrc = getselectedsource(depthVid);
  depthSrc.EnableBodyTracking = 'on';
```